# "Method 'Value' of object 'Range' failed" and excel crashes

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I have created a userform and one of the commandbuttons launches another userform in which data can be entered into. This data is then added to a table in a worksheet, the userform is then unloaded and the user is returned to the original userform. The error occurs when the data is meant to be entered into the worksheet. This userform works perfectly on its own, but when it is launched from the first userform, this is when the error occurs.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    'check all fields are filled
    Dim nextRow As Integer
    Dim nextCell As String

    If Len(Trim(ComboBox1.Value)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "All feilds must be filled"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Len(Trim(TextBox1.Value)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "All feilds must be filled"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Len(Trim(TextBox2.Value)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "All feilds must be filled"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Check if supplier ID already exists
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range

    FindString = TextBox1.Value

        If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
            With Sheet4.Range("B:B")
                Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
                If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                    Application.Goto Rng, False
                    MsgBox "Sorry Bro, " & FindString & " already exists!"
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    FindString = TextBox2

                        If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
                            With Sheet4.Range("D:D")
                                Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                                                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                                MatchCase:=False)
                                If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                                    Application.Goto Rng, False
                                    MsgBox "Sorry Bro, the Ordering Details you entered:" & vbNewLine & _
                                            "'" & FindString & "'" & vbNewLine & _
                                            "Already exists in our Database!" & vbNewLine & _
                                            "U wanna check ur data?"
                                    Exit Sub
                                End If
                            End With
                        End If

                End If
            End With
        End If



    'enter supplier ID into sheet
    Sheet4.Activate
    nextRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Count
    nextCell = Cells(nextRow + 2, 2).Activate

    'this is where the error occurs
    ActiveCell.Value = TextBox1.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ComboBox1.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = TextBox2.Value

    Sheet2.Activate

    Unload Me
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it doesn't work because personally I avoid the use of "Activate". Maybe you can try if this works:

```
    'Previous code that worked fine

    nextRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Count

    With ActiveSheet.Cells(nextRow + 2, 2)
        .Value = TextBox1.Value
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = ComboBox1.Value
        .Offset(0, 2).Value = TextBox2.Value
    End With
    Sheet2.Activate

    Unload Me
    End Sub
```

Hope this does the job! (Note that this is my first answer so I'm very open to feedback)